# Two Arabic font representations in unicode

Tags: unicode, arabic, typography, arabic-support

I am working on an application with arabic text and I found that there are always two ways to write the same text in arabic. I am unable to understand why is it happening and how can I convert anyone of them to the other to develop a consistent UI.

Here's is an example of an arabic phrase.

> اللّهُمَّ صَلِّ عَلَى مُحَمَّدٍ وَآلِ مُحَمَّدٍ
>
> اَﻟﻠّﻬُﻢﱠ ﺻَﻞﱢ ﻋَﻠﻰ ﻣُﺤَﻤﱠﺪٍ وَ ﺁلِ ﻣُﺤَﻤﱠﺪٍ

I see that it is looking the same in preview but it is different, I wanna achieve the same result.

Here's how I can differentiate these two in Notes

[image: screenshot of notes to show the difference]

Answer (score 0):

They look different in my browser and getting the Unicode code points for each gives me, in order posted

```
U+627 U+644 U+644 U+651 U+647 U+64F U+645 U+651 U+64E U+20 U+635 U+64E U+644 U+651 U+650 U+20 U+639 U+64E U+644 U+64E U+649 U+20 U+645 U+64F U+62D U+64E U+645 U+651 U+64E U+62F U+64D U+20 U+648 U+64E U+622 U+644 U+650 U+20 U+645 U+64F U+62D U+64E U+645 U+651 U+64E U+62F U+64D

U+627 U+64E U+FEDF U+FEE0 U+651 U+FEEC U+64F U+FEE2 U+FC60 U+20 U+FEBB U+64E U+FEDE U+FC62 U+20 U+FECB U+64E U+FEE0 U+FEF0 U+20 U+FEE3 U+64F U+FEA4 U+64E U+FEE4 U+FC60 U+FEAA U+64D U+20 U+648 U+64E U+20 U+FE81 U+644 U+650 U+20 U+FEE3 U+64F U+FEA4 U+64E U+FEE4 U+FC60 U+FEAA U+64D
```

Checking these the first three letters on the first line is ALEF, LAM, LAM and the second line is ALEF, FATHA, LAM INITIAL FORM

Which is odd because the initial form should not come in the middle of a word. Looks like your data is not correctly cleaned. I don't know, except for checking each letter, of a way to fix this.

Comment: Well, did your browser not show both of them correctly but in different fonts. Actually the issue is not only with LAM INITIAL FORM or full form but it is typically with the two sequences of arabic characters present in each font.

Comment: The 2 lines of text are in the same font for me. However I have just pasted them both into Libra Office and discovered that  the second line has some text direction override characters in it

Comment: `They look different in my browser` ?